# The footer is not where it is supposed to be

Tags: html, css, django

I just faced a problem and I can't resolve it. I don't understand why the footer comes between the button of my calendar and the calendar itself.

Callendar.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Calendar
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:event_new' %}"> New Imputation </a>
</div>
{{calendar}}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html :

```
<div class="wrapper">

{% include "header.html" %}

{% include "menu.html" %}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
      {% block title_page %}{% endblock %}
    </section>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
        {% block content %}       
        {% endblock %}       
    </section>     
</div>
{% include "footer.html" %}
</div>
```

and the view of of my calendar :

Views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/userprofile/login/'), name='dispatch')
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'cal/calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        return context
```

As the result actually i got this when i press F12 (inspect element) on the web page :

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="/calendrier/calendar/?month=2020-6"> Previous Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="/calendrier/calendar/?month=2020-8"> Next Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="/calendrier/event/new/"> New Imputation </a>
</div>
<footer class="main-footer">    
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        Version X.x
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright © 2019 <a href="#">CONDUENT</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
    
    </footer><div>
  
</div><table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="calendar">
```

As you can see the footer goes beetween the button class and the table (who is the calendar) Ask me if you need to see the Css but as i saw that's not the problem.

All i want is the footer go where is supposed to be :c

Comment: why you include `{% include "footer.html" %}`  between two closing tags

Comment: i've tried to move it outer of the div content wrapper but it ddin't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the block endings

Callendar.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title_page %}
Calendar
{% endblock title_page %}

{% block content %}
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:event_new' %}"> New Imputation </a>
</div>
{{calendar}}
{% endblock content %}
```

base.html :

```
<div class="wrapper">

{% include "header.html" %}

{% include "menu.html" %}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
      {% block title_page %}{% endblock title_page %}
    </section>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
        {% block content %}       
        {% endblock content %}       
    </section>     
</div>
{% include "footer.html" %}
</div>
```

also do similar thing on your "menu.html", "header.html" and "footer.html" too!